# Is there a way to have a static IP address on PC if I'm using USB tethering?

Tags: xiaomi, usb-tethering, dhcp

I need a static IP address on my PC. It uses a USB tethered phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 10) for internet connection, so I'm not sure how to go about that. I tried to assign one through network settings on PC but that failed.

Could I root my phone and install some third-party app to change my network settings? If so, what apps do I need to get? Are there any methods other than the one I've mentioned that could work as well?

My knowledge on messing with Android devices is extremely poor, and I'm not that much more knowledgeable on computer networks, so I apologize in advance for any clueless-ness.

Comment: Assigning a static IP should be no problem as long as you choose an IP from the same subnet and use the correct subnet mask. Connect your PC to the hotspot to get a dynmic IP and then look in the settings and tell us the assigned IP address and the network mask. The wen can tell you which IPs you can use as static IP.

Comment: Hey @Robert, it seems like I have the same problem (for some reason, I cant access (simple HTTP server on) the tethered device using the IP from `ipconfig` - `192.168.54.60`. Phone's IP is `192.168.0.102`.
Subnet mask on both devices is `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: For additional context I am able to access it when it's not tethered and is connected via lan. Wifi doesn't work on the PC that's why I need to tether it to the phone which can connect to wifi.

Comment: @pu239 Why do you use two IPs from different subnets? Please use one of the available online network mask calculators to learn what IPs belong to your subnet.